# meaning of failure message upon startup

Tags: boot, laptop, broadcom, mac

I managed to get my wireless connection to work on my macbook air (late 2015 vintage) and am pleased with that success. There are problems and questions, though. The wireless interface is a Broadcom usb device, which does not now show up with the lsusb command. (Neither does the built-in camera, also a Broadcom device.)
The computer seems to run well, but now I'd like to try to get the camera working too...but cannot find it, anymore.
When I boot the computer I get a message screen with some error/failure messages. I would like to know the meaning of the message and what to do about it.
[image: image is a photograph of the failure message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make a change in your `/boot` to resolve this. Here's how:

1. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
2. Switch to the super user:

   ```
   $ sudo su -
   ```
3. Go to the Ubuntu EFI directory:

   ```
   $ cd /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu
   ```
4. Copy `grubx64.efi` to `shimx64.efi`:

   ```
   $ cp grubx64.efi shimx64.efi
   ```
5. Reboot the machine

This should resolve the message